# How to make div fill whole the height possible of its parent?

Tags: css

I have this design
https://jsfiddle.net/49hsztuh/

Here is the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>
@charset "utf-8";
html,body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

.chatContainer {
    font-family:Nunito; 
    font-size:0.9em;
    background-color:red;
    height:800px;
}
.chatHeader {
    height:50px;
    background-color:#363b3f;
    color:white;
    padding-left:10px;
}

#myWebcamDiv {
    height:260px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:black;
    padding:0px;
}

#chatUsers {
    margin-top:10px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    width:100%;
    height:320px;
    background-color:blue;
}
#chatCams {
    width:100%;
    background-color:#FeFeFe;
    padding:0px;
    display:inline-block;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    overflow-x:auto;
    white-space: nowrap;

}
.chatText {
    height:250px;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:yellow;
    color:black;
    overflow-x:none;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}

</style>

</head>

<div class="col-md-12 chatContainer">

    <div class="chatHeader"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4" id="chatLeftColumn" >
        <div id="myWebcamDiv"></div>        

        <div id="chatUsers"></div>        
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-8" id="chatRightColumn">
        <div id="chatCams"></div>       
        <div role="tabpanel">

          <!-- Nav tabs -->
          <ul id="pageTab" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">

          <li class="active">
          <a  href="#LoungeRoom" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">LoungeRoom</a></li></ul>

          <!-- Tab panes -->
          <div id="pageTabContent" class="tab-content">
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active chatText" id="LoungeRoom"></div>
            <div class="tab-pane chatText" id="LoungeRoom"></div>
          </div>

        </div>    


        <div id="chatInputDiv"></div>            

    </div>

</div>
```

My goal is to make **the blue and yellow divs filled up to the bottom of the red container**. (make sure you view the fiddle with a min width).

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Start by giving the children the same height as their parent. This will guarantee they flow at least until the bottom of their parent. If they start lower than their parent's top, they will overflow passed the bottom of their parent.

```
#chatUsers {
    margin-top:10px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    width:100%;
    height:800px; /* height of parent */
    background-color:blue;
}

.chatText {
    height:800px; /* height of parent */
    padding:10px;
    background-color:yellow;
    color:black;
    overflow-x:none;
    overflow-y:scroll;  
}
```

Then use the overflow:hidden property on the parent to hide the overflowing children.

```
.chatContainer {
    font-family:Nunito; 
    font-size:0.9em;
    background-color:red;
    height:800px;
    overflow: hidden; /* hide overflow */
}
```

Comment: I put parent height as 800px.. but of course can be another height.

So this solution is not flexible enough !

Comment: Your question should have been posed using a flexible height. Take a look at this: http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/